# insert and return document in a single AQL query

Tags: arangodb, aql

When I insert a document into a collection with AQL it returns an empty list.

```
arangosh [test]> db._query('INSERT @document INTO vertices', {document: {name: "bar"}}).toArray()
[ ]
```

Is there a way to insert a document and get the complete document back in a single AQL query?

What I am hoping to get back is:

```
{
  "_id": "vertices/641272433780",
  "_key": "641272433780",
  "_rev": "641272433780",
  "name": "bar"
}
```

Comment: We are currently working on this (returning whole documents from AQL data-modification operations), but the feature is not completed yet. I can post here when there are news.

Comment: Great to hear! Are there plans to allow data-modification operations in subqueries?

Comment: Not at the moment, as this would require massive changes in AQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the feature is implemented, its going to look like that:

```
INSERT expression IN|INTO collection [ OPTIONS expression ] WITH NEW INTO variable RETURN variable;

REMOVE expression IN|INTO collection [ OPTIONS expression ] WITH OLD INTO variable RETURN variable;

UPDATE expression IN|INTO collection [ OPTIONS expression ] WITH OLD|NEW INTO variable RETURN variable
UPDATE expression WITH expression IN|INTO collection [ OPTIONS expression ] WITH OLD|NEW INTO variable RETURN variable
```

`

Comment: I wonder if there would be any use of a `BOTH` pseudo-variable to get the old and the new back...

Comment: This appears to have been implemented in ArangoDB 2.4: http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/01/13/returning-results-from-aql-insert-update-remove-operations/

Answer (score 4):

This is possible since ArangoDB 2.4. To return the created document, the original query

```
INSERT @document INTO vertices
```

has to be changed into

```
INSERT @document INTO vertices LET result = NEW RETURN result
```

This will also work for multi-document INSERTs and also for UPDATE/REPLACE and REMOVE. The following quotes from the [2.4 documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/DataModification.html) describe the syntax:

> To return documents from a data-modification query, the INSERT, REMOVE, UPDATE or REPLACE statement must be immediately followed by a LET statement that assigns either the pseudo-value NEW or OLD to a user-defined variable. The LET statement must be followed by a RETURN statement that returns the variable introduced by LET.
>
> NEW refers to the inserted or modified document revision, and OLD refers to the document revision before update or removal. INSERT statements can only refer to the NEW pseudo-value, and REMOVE operations only to OLD. UPDATE and REPLACE can refer to either.

Comment: Also works with upsert

Comment: I think `RETURN NEW` works too now, without assigning it to a variable